# Ubuntu 14.04 and iPod touch 6th generation: how to transfer music files?

Tags: ipod

I've tried gtkpod and it doesn't support new ipods like mine. I have ios 9.2.1. All I want to do is put music on my ipod and take music off of my ipod. Please help me!

Comment: As Ubuntu 14.04 was released almost 2 years ago it does't contains the software to handle last iOS versions. You can either compile and manualy upgrade libimobiledevice http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ or wait until Ubuntu 16.04 is released and upgrade. Take in mind this is a never ending story with every major iOS update almost always breaking libimobiledevice support since 2010. Consider either instead using a more friendly device or contact Apple and let them know your problem.